# Plotting with matplotlib/cartopy: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

Ok, I'm having a hard time understanding this one. A few days ago this code worked fine and I produced dozens of maps with it. Now it's not working anymore. I reverted a conda update I did in the meantime back to months ago and it still doesn't work. I'm trying to plot a 2D array using pcolormesh on a cartopy axis.

I'm using versions Python==3.6.10, Cartopy==0.17.0 and Matplotlib==3.3.3.

Here's the code I'm using and below are workarounds I've tried but failed. Dimensions for the variables are lats `(8520)`, lons `(7320)` and meanp `(8520, 7320)`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

matplotlib.rcParams.update({'font.size': 20})

fig = plt.figure(figsize=[10,10])

# 111 means 1 row, 1 col and index 1
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_extent((-80, -41,-20,8.7), crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

#Mean Annual Precipitation
data = xarray.open_dataset("SAMERICA_PP.nc")
meanp = data.pp.values
lons = data.lon.values
lats = data.lat.values

im = ax.pcolormesh(lons, lats, meanp, cmap='plasma', vmax=0.7)
```

This is the error I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-7c9ae7fe17bf> in <module>
     33 
     34 
---> 35 im = ax.pcolormesh(lons, lats, meanp,cmap='plasma',vmax=0.7)
     36 
     37

~/anaconda3/envs/amazon/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cartopy/mpl/geoaxes.py in pcolormesh(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1457                              ' consider using PlateCarree/RotatedPole.')
   1458         kwargs.setdefault('transform', t)
-> 1459         result = self._pcolormesh_patched(*args, **kwargs)
   1460         self.autoscale_view()
   1461         return result

~/anaconda3/envs/amazon/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cartopy/mpl/geoaxes.py in _pcolormesh_patched(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1489         allmatch = (shading == 'gouraud')
   1490 
-> 1491         X, Y, C = self._pcolorargs('pcolormesh', *args, allmatch=allmatch)
   1492         Ny, Nx = X.shape
   1493 

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

I have tried setting `shading=auto` or `shading=nearest` inside the call to `pcolormesh`, setting `matplotlib.rcParams['pcolor.shading'] ='nearest'` and even calling `pcolormesh` with `X,Y = np.meshgrid(lons,lats)`. All throw the same error.

Interestingly I can plot the data with a call to `plt.pcolormesh` outside the script, so I think the error is in the cartopy-derived projection axes call in `ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())`.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Check `lons.shape, lats.shape, meanp.shape`, all of them must be the same. Usually `meshgrid` is needed to get proper values to use with `pcolormesh()`.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is fixed in `cartopy` version `0.19`. So it is probably safer to update if you should ever use it with older `matplotlib` versions.

I have been having the same issue and turns out it is a minor incompatibility with `cartopy` and `matplotlib` (probably since `>3.3` versions).

`Matplotlib` version `3.2.2`:

`_axes.py`, `_pcolorargs` function return 3 arguments (line 5790): i.e.

```
return X, Y, C
```

Matplotlib version 3.4.3:

`_axes.py`, `_pcolorargs` function return 4 arguments (line 5627):

```
return X, Y, C, shading
```

Now Cartopy version 0.17:

`geoaxes.py` uses `matplotlib _pcolorargs` functions as (line 1755):

```
X, Y, C = self._pcolorargs('pcolormesh', *args, allmatch=allmatch)
```

So.. 3 arguments, but `matplotlib` gives 4 with the 'shading' argument, thus causing the `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3), since it is given 4.`

So, a quick fix (that worked for me without updating) was to go to my installed `cartopy` (version `0.17`) source code on `~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cartopy/mpl/geoaxes.py` and add the 'shading' argument there, so my line 1491 looks like:

```
X, Y, C, shading = self._pcolorargs('pcolormesh', *args, allmatch=allmatch)
```

And boom, now `pcolormesh` works fine again!